# How to return correct value from Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, api

I want to call an API in my function which returns an array, and I want to know the length of the array. The code below is a rough implementation.

```
function count() {
    var count;
    $.ajax({
        url: "...",
        success: function (array) {
            count = array.length;
        }
    });
    if (count >= 0) {
        return count;
    } else {
        alert(count);
    }
}
```

This is not working as count is not returning the array's length and alert(count) returns `undefined`, how do I fix this?

Comment: Logically, you code is not right. $.ajax is a asynchronous call. count value will not be updated when it reaches the end of code. That is why you get undefined.

Comment: @wannadream that's true, should I be returning count inside the success statement

Comment: I don't think return will return the value to parent count() method. I suggest you to try Promise() or create a setInterval to monitor the value.

Comment: Are you sure if its returning an array ?

Comment: You should do whatever you want to do with the count inside the success method. The value does not exist outside it and also you can't know when you'll have the value available, that's why you have to treat it inside there.

Comment: I might have to use a promise

Answer (score 0):

You will not have access to the value of count until your asynchronous response returns. Your function is synchronous and does not wait for the result of count before attempting to read it. The simplest solution is to scope your logic in the success callback:

`function count() {
  var count;
  $.ajax({
    url: "...",
    success: function (array) {
      count = array.length;
      if (count >= 0) {
        return count;
      } else {
        alert(count);
      }
    }
  });
}`

**UPDATE**

I simply copied the return block for simplicity. I did not optimize it. My purpose was to show that using the `success callback` is the quickest way to get a response. Consider this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/6369/).

Comment: I don't think this will return `count` from the `count()` function since it's async.

Comment: Will 'return count;' actually returns the value to its parent?? I don't think so.

Comment: this won't work as the result is not returned to parent